# Any problems using a M1 Macbook pro with a 34" ultrawide external monitor

Tags: display

I am currently using 2 22" dell monitors for external displays.  I would like to have more space for displaying code in vscode.  I use displaylink to get it to work with external monitors and am wondering if there will be any problems with the wider screen.  Any suggestions from those software developers who use multiple monitors would be welcome.

Comment: Does this help? (scroll down to 2nd display support) https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-m1-8-core-13-2020-specs.html

Comment: That helps to know I can add an external monitor with 6016x3384 (6K) at 60 Hz specs.  I have heard that new M1 processor only supports 1 external display where as the older macbooks supported more.  The only way I found around this is to install the displaylink manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a 34" 34GK950F with a M1 Air and it works fine at 60hz, using a usb-c -> DisplayPort cable. I've had no issues with VSC or any of my dev tools using it.

The M1 only supports one external monitor (up to 6k/60hz), although it seems some people have used displaylink to add more but you run into incompatibility issues:
https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/how-connect-two-or-more-external-displays-apple-silicon-m1-mac-3799794/